# Does coroutine.yield() returns control back do SDK in NodeMCU eLua firmware?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I've been reading https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/lua-developer-faq/#esp8266-specifics and the document says that the Lua code need to return so that SDK can run other tasks:

> All other service and application processing is split into code execution blocks, known as tasks. The individual tasks are executed one at a time and run to completion. No task can never pre-empt another.

and

> The Lua libraries work in consort with the SDK to queue pending events and invoke any registered Lua callback routines, which then run to completion uninterrupted.

Then PiL says that yield can be used to suspend function calls which may be resumed later:

> The real power of coroutines stems from the yield function, which allows a running coroutine to suspend its execution so that it can be resumed later.

My question is: Does the NodeMCU's eLua implementation return the control to SDK when `coroutine.yield(c)` is executed? ... So that would be possible to implement cooperative multithreaded algorithms with NodeMCU/eLua firwmare?

How does `coroutine.resume(c)` would work in this context?